# The announcer keeps mocking me. How do I shut him up?

Tags: sonic-and-sega-all-stars-racing

I am playing Sonic and SEGA All Stars Racing and it seems like the announcer doesn't like me very much. He keeps mocking my racing and being rather annoying.

Is there a way to shut him up so he stops driving me crazy?

Comment: I assume other than mute your TV? :P

Comment: Ullallulloo beat me too it :P

Comment: Yeah, ideally, I would like something other than muting my TV. I like the other in-game sounds.

Comment: Shoot him in his knee with an arrow. ^_^

Comment: i bought him a birthday gift. it was awkward at first - he hadn't had a friend before. we went fishing together. a cold breeze skating over waters. over time, shared failures with helped success, summer chased away the cold. he's only ever been supportive of me since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the game any more, but I think if you go into Settings > Audio Settings there may be an option to turn off the commentary (maybe depends on which platform?)

Comment: Yeah, there is an option in the audio settings to turn him off completely. Hurrah!